# transient data structure creation using `repeat`

Tags: clojure

I want to use transients to create a large data structure. Here is the code without transients:

```
(into [] (repeat 10 :a))
;; => [:a :a :a :a :a :a :a :a :a :a]
```

My naive attempt would be this:

```
(persistent! (into (transient []) (repeat 10 :a)))
```

I can get the error message just with this:

```
(into (transient []) (repeat 10 :a))
;; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector$TransientVector cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection  clojure.core/conj--6410 (core.clj:82)
```

Is it wrong to be trying to use `repeat`? (There's no such function `repeat!`). What is a better way?

Comment: `I want to use transients to create a large data structure` please explain why / what are you actually trying to do, and what are your expectations ?

Comment: My day 6 for advent of code 2015 is slow. So trying to speed it up. Thinking about the call `mk-state` first. See: https://github.com/chrismurrph/advent-of-code/blob/master/dev/advent_2015/day06.clj

Comment: `into` already uses transients internally, so even if you did this manually you would not get any speedup. You should measure first to find out your bottleneck!

Comment: You're essentially doing BITBLT operations. I'd try using a bit inside a `long` instead of an object for each element. This give you up to 64 times fewer operations to do. You can use plain mutable Java arrays - created with  `long-array` - for each row of lights. These initialise to zero by default, so your question as asked simply disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `into` function uses `conj` internally.  With transients, you need the `conj!` function instead.  For example:

```
(defn transient-range [limit]
  (loop [cnt 0 
         cum (transient []) ]
    (if (< cnt limit)
      (recur  (inc cnt)  (conj! cum cnt))
      (persistent! cum))))

(println (transient-range 20))

;=> [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

For a transient `repeat`, just do this:

```
(defn transient-repeat [qty value]
  (loop [cnt 0 
         cum (transient []) ]
    (if (< cnt qty)
      (recur  (inc cnt)  (conj! cum value))
      (persistent! cum))))

(println (transient-repeat 5 42))

;=> [42 42 42 42 42]
```

Please see full details here:  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/transient

Comment: From what you have there it is easy to get `transient-repeat` I think? Instead of `(conj! cum cnt)` have `(conj! cum value)`, with value being the second parameter.

Comment: If a faster `repeat` is all you're after, I'm not sure you'll be able to beat the built-in Clojure function, which is coded in native Java.

Comment: "The `into` function uses `conj` internally" – actually `into` uses transients automatically when possible, see my answer. Additionally, while it's always good to benchmark, `reduce`-based looping over vectors is extremely well optimized and should be significantly faster than `loop` / `recur`. So the original expression in the question text (`(into [] …)`) is already among the best possible approaches (`(vec …)` being the most obvious equally good alternative).

Answer (score 6):

**`into` uses transients automatically whenever possible.**

That is to say, the first thing `into` does is it checks whether its first argument has a transient version (whether it implements `clojure.lang.IEditableCollection):

1. if it does, then `into` uses `transient` + `reduce` + `conj!` + `persistent` (and on top of that, `with-meta` + `meta` to preserve metadata);
2. otherwise it uses `reduce` + `conj`.

[Here's the source as of Clojure 1.8](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6604) if you'd like to confirm the details. (In particular, note that all of the above is also true of the ternary overload that takes a transducer.)

So your original expression, `(into [] (repeat 10 :a))` already uses transients and is, in fact, the best way to use transients here. Any explicit mention of `transient` / `conj!` / etc. is entirely superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that is the bottleneck, because your original approch is quite fast for this sample size:

```
(defn mk-state-prev [value width height]
  (vec (repeat height (vec (repeat width value)))))

(time (doall (mk-state-prev 3 1000 1000)))
"Elapsed time: 0.284245 msecs"

(time (get-in (mk-state-prev 3 1000 1000) [100 101] :not-found))
"Elapsed time: 0.305037 msecs" 
3 ; found `3`
```

this begs the next question:

How have you been measuring "time" ?

---

regarding your [`mk-state`](https://github.com/chrismurrph/advent-of-code/blob/master/dev/advent_2015/day06.clj#L11) - here is one approach i tired, but it is slower

```
(defn mk-state [value width height]
  (let [v (transient (vector))
        row (vec (repeat height value))] ; only create 1 row
    (doseq [n (range 0 width)] 
      (conj! v row)) ; mutate (add rows)
    (persistent! v)))

(set! *print-length* 5)
; otherwise the repl will propably hang with printing 1e6 items

(time (doall (mk-state :t 1000 1000)))
"Elapsed time: 1.366543 msecs"
```

---

EDIT2:

> @birdspider You can NOT bash your transient into place like this. Check the return value, it's incorrect. – ClojureMostly 16 hours ago

how is this not correct ? not a rant - please educate me :)

```
Clojure 1.8.0
(defn mk-state [value width height]
  (let [v (transient (vector))
        row (vec (repeat height value))] ; only create 1 row
    (doseq [n (range 0 width)] 
      (conj! v row)) ; mutate (add rows)
    (persistent! v)))
#'user/mk-state
user=> (get-in (mk-state :t 1000 1000) [99 99])
:t
user=> (pprint (mk-state :t 10 10))
[[:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]
 [:t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t :t]]
nil
```

Comment: I got the idea for speeding things up from https://github.com/bhauman/advent-of-clojure/blob/master/src/advent/day06.clj. Just my first look at transients, not solving any particular bottleneck problem. As you can see from the link to really speed things up put more of the mutations within the bounds of the `persistent!` call.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy I understand, but calls to `transistant` and `perisistant!` do incur an (albeit constant) overhead, so if they are a good fit really depends on the underlying problem - that being said, I'm by no means an expert and there may well be patterns where their usage is generally favourable

Comment: I just assumed Bruce's code would be much faster due to the use of transients. But in fact it is much slower. So you make a good point.

Comment: @birdspider You can *NOT* bash your transient into place like this. Check the return value, it's incorrect.

Comment: @ClojureMostly you are most likely correct - but I did check the returned coll and could `(get-in .. [101 101])` and got `:t` - see EDIT2

Comment: You're just lucky that it works, it's an implementation detail. The API clearly specifies that you CANNOT do this: https://clojure.org/reference/transients If the implemntation detail changes in the future your function will break. FYI: A hash map transient will change the implementation underneath you and your function wont work.

Comment: @ClojureMostly - ah you mean I should use whatever `(conj!` returns instead of the let bound transient `v` again and again. Thank you - I didn't know that, then again, the 'Note' on the reference page is quite easy to miss.